# Convert a nullable integer value in Java (Short, Long etc.)

Tags: java

Is there any standard way of converting between non-primitive integer types in Java that properly retains `null` values? Something like:

```
// Pseudocode
Short shortVal = null;
Long longVal = Numbers.toLong(shortVal); // longVal is expected to be null here
```

Obviously I cannot use `shortVal.longValue()` here as a `NullPointerException` will be thrown.

Comment: If you're using java >= 8, [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) may be interesting to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain simple "casting" and the "ternary conditional operator" would be the minimal and fastest solution.

```
Short shortVal = null;
Long longVal = shortVal == null ? null : (long) shortVal;
```

Since you don't seem to know about casting, here's an example that **does not** work - and how to fix it. Mind that the problem of null is completely ignored here - this is just a quirky aspect of casting that you might want to know, that's all.

```
Double doubleVal = 1d;
Float floatVal = (float) doubleVal; // Inconvertible types!
```

Working version:

```
Double doubleVal = 1d;
Float floatVal = (float) (double) doubleVal;
```

Comment: I do know about casting, but casting here would once again yield a `NullPointerException`, hence my question.

Comment: Oh ok. Well, there's really no shorter/faster way than adding a ternary value check and then either casting or just assigning null yourself. - Thanks for accepting my answer. (I think it's my first.)

Answer (score 0):

What about using the Java 8 API Optional:

```
Short shortVal = null;
Optional<Long> longVal = Optional.ofNullable(shortVal != null ? new Long(shortVal) : null);
System.out.println(longVal.isPresent());
```

The output for this code snippet is `false`, which indicates that the value is null.

Comment: Seems a bit of an overkill in this situation, my primary goal was simplicity.

Comment: That's absolutely fine, just thought I'd give you another option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
Short shortVal = null;
Long longVal = Optional.ofNullable(shortVal)
     .map(short -> (long) short).orElse(null);
```

Answer (score -2):

How about:

```
Long longVal = shortVal != null ? Numbers.toLong(shortVal) : null;
```

Comment: `Numbers` doesn't exist in Java, that's exactly the thing I'm looking for.

Comment: @yktoo want to create such a class?

Comment: It surprises me JDK doesn't have one, seems a very common use case to me.