# Null-safe Integer.longValue() in Java?

Tags: java

In Java, you can convert `Integer` to `Long` with built-in method `longValue()` but it is not null-safe:

```java
Integer value = null;
Long result = value.longValue(); // NPE
```

Is there a **short** and **convenient** way to do null-safe conversion of `Integer` to `Long` in Java?

I.e., something like

```java
Long result = Long.longValue(value);
```

with this simple implementation (and / or potentially overloadings for different number types):

```java
public static Long longValue(Integer value) {
    return value != null ? value.longValue() : null;
}
```

I can not find such an implementation in both Java Standard Library and some other popular libraries (including Apache Commons, Guava and Spring).

I could either add this method myself but *it does not look convenient*.

I could also write something like this

```java
Long result = value != null ? value.longValue() : null;
Long result = Optional.ofNullable(value).map(Integer::longValue).orElse(null);
```

but *neither of these options look short*. Especially when `value` is not just a value but is actually some function with long name and multiple arguments.

Maybe I have missed something and there is such a method in any of the popular libraries?

Thanks!

Comment: Java generally doesn't do "short and convenient". I recommend upgrading to Kotlin, which has null-safety built in: `intValue?.toLong()`. The nice thing is, it's fully compatible with Java, you can even compile projects that have sources in both languages and combine them together.

Comment: You prefer adding an external dependency to your project over writing a one-line helper method? You do realize that managing that dependency is **much** more work than implementing that helper method, right?

Comment: There is no such built-in method in Java. I'd follow the way with helper methods

Comment: @ThomasBehr usually Apache Commons and/or Guava are already added as dependencies to most enterprise projects. There are many helpful utility methods in them but I'm surprised there is apparently no such method there, though.

Comment: @Jorn in enterprise software development, migrating to a different language is unfortunately painful. Even though they are compatible, there could be other reasons for being conservative in technological stack.

Comment: If you really want to use Java, and you really want *short* and *convenient* then `import static` and use your helper method. Nothing in Java allows you to add methods to the `NullType`. So you're not going to find a library that does this.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch you mean writing this method yourself? If you have many microservices you'll need to do this in every of them which is definitely not convenient (or moving them to your custom library which could be even worse).

Comment: @dimnnv True, but complaining about that isn't going to help. Your options are either working within the language or switching to another.

Comment: @dimnnv You already wrote `public static Long longValue(Integer value)` (and that implementation looks fine). Put it in a utility class and `import static` when you need it. Again, you (and nobody else either) can't add methods to the `NullType` so there really isn't another option. Best of luck!

Comment: @Jorn I could have missed if this method already exists in some popular library. That's why the question was asked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a nullable integer value in Java (Short, Long etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49193021/convert-a-nullable-integer-value-in-java-short-long-etc)

Comment: @MaksymKosenko probably does not as it is does not seek non-JDK solutions but I hope to find some.

Comment: There is no any, just like the accepted answer sounds, the shortest way is a ternary operator if you are not considering any static util method somewhere in a helper

Comment: @MaksymKosenko as you see it was accepted more than 5 years ago and the situation might have changed since then. But I do not have very much hope of course.

Comment: _Objective-C_ is probably the only language more verbose than _Java_.  I imagine the most effective way is to use the ternary.  _Long result = value != null ? value.longValue() : null;_.  Or, if you're using it frequently, use your _longValue_ method.  I don't believe there is any quick solution.